# AttributeError: 'particleAnimation' object has no attribute 'animate'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been scripting with Python for a bit but now I'm delving into classes and OOP.

I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "practice.py", line 10, in <module>
    l.animate(2,"L...R.L..")
    AttributeError: 'particleAnimation' object has no attribute 'animate'
```

...when I run this code:

```
class particleAnimation(object):
    def __init__(self):

        def animate(self, speed, init):
            self.speed = speed
            self.init = init

l = particleAnimation()
print("test")
l.animate(2,"L...R.L..")

print(line1)
```

I am running Python 3.6.3. Why do I get this exception?

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget that **indentation matters in Python!**

With your current indentation, `animate` belongs to `__init__` instead of your `particleAnimation` class.

Here's what you should have, notice that **`__init__` and `animate` have the same level of indentation**:

```
class particleAnimation(object):
    def __init__(self):
        ...

    def animate(self, speed, init):
        ...
```